# C programs stuck

Tags: windows-10, c

After installing windows 10 a couple of month ago i tryed to run a very simple C program, firtsly in Visual Studio 2015, and the entire IDE froze. Then I tried compiling via command line. The build is always succesfull with no problems but when i try to run a program nothing happens, the terminal just doesn't do anything and I can't even go back. Sometimes I can't even kill the process the .exe file generated even though I'm using an admin account!

I tried the easiest program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    system("pause");     //or getchar()
    return 0;
}
```

and the result is just the flashing white underscore in a terminal that I can't even close. I've tried every compiler and every different C/C++ IDE possible, this is so strange, it must be a Windows problem please help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,
I found a temporary solution was to disable Antivirus checking as stated here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958842/c-cli-application-hanging-after-compiling-on-windows-10
Adding the build folder to the virus scanner's exclusions worked.